# How does C++ parallel_reduce use the inital value parameter?

Tags: parallel-processing, c++17, tbb

I expect the following code snippet to produce the sum of all the elements and the initial value but it doesn't:

```
    vector<long> a;
    a.resize(10);
    generate(a.begin(), a.end(), [n = 1]() mutable { return n++; });
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    sum = parallel_reduce(a.begin(), a.end(), 10);
    assert(sum == 65); // 11 * 5 + 10. It produces 215 instead.
#endif
```

Instead of the expected `65`, it produces `215`. Even if every element is added by `10`, `31 * 5 = 155`, not `215`. How does `215` come about?
What do I miss? Any reference that explains how the initial value is used is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not really provide a MCVE as the code snippet in question does not compile, but one problem is still apparent: you assume the last argument to `parallel_reduce` is the initial value, while according to documentation it's identity value.

Identity for addition is 0 and if you pass that, you will get expected result (55).

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 and therefore the `#ifdef`. Where can I find documentation on the third parameter?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [docs for parallel_reduce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrency-namespace-functions?view=msvc-170#parallel_reduce)? Other that that, I understand the `#ifdef`, but there are no `#include`s, no function definition, nor anything else that would help us helping you.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about what value to use for the identify for various reductions at all except some cryptic descriptions.

Comment: Because it can't. If you provide the reduction operation, only you know its identity value. For addition it is 0, for multiplication is it 1, for string concatenation it is "" (empty string).

Comment: Where is the official documentation for this?

Comment: Please do some research on your own. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) is a great start.

Comment: The documentation for `tbb::parallel_reduce `specifies that the value is a left identity.  https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_reduce_func.html .  @KrzysiekKarbowiak 's Wikipedia link explain identity elements.